# R, lectura de textos planos o ficheros de texto por lineas

Tags: r, archivo

Tenia una duda acerca de la lectura de ficheros de datos en el lenguaje R.
Quiero leer un archivo txt de caracteres por líneas. Por ejemplo supongamos que tenemos el siguiente archivo que se llame 'archivo' que tiene las siguientes lineas :
Hola pepito grillo
hoy hace un buen dia
mañana será nublado

Lo que quiero es que me lo lea y lo guarde en una estructura de datos donde pueda saber que por ejemplo 'hola pepito grillo ' corresponde a la primera linea.
He probado con scan(file='archivo', what= character())
pero no me lo guarda por lineas.

Answer (score 1):

Vale justamente, me acabo de dar cuenta de como se hace.

se hace con scan(file= 'archivo', what=character(), sep='\n')

indicándole la separación por el intro.